# mlogit error "non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Tags: r, mlogit

I ran this statement:

`clogitdf <- mlogit.data(df1, choice= "y", shape="long", alt.var="alt", chid="chid")`

And here's a dput of the first 48 lines of the dataset (replaced with dput of df1): http://pastebin.com/RNJBRhGr

I get an error saying "non-numeric argument to binary operator" running this:

`reg2 <- mlogit(y ~ PriceNorm, data=clogitdf, id.var="id_var", reflevel="surf")`

I've been having a lot of issues with dataset already, so I basically tried to match the format from section 1 of this example: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/Exercises.pdf

My data pretty much matches exactly, but I get an error when I try to run `mlogit`.

Any thoughts?

Edit: I should add that mlogit.data wasn't putting `y` into TRUE/FALSE format, and had already written a While/if statement to replace column values, so that's how those got there. I'm not sure if that's a problem that I did it that way.

Edit2: Replaced pastebin with dput of `df1`

Comment: Can you share `dput(df1)` rather than `clogitdf`? I think the problem might be the `mlogit.data()` call but i'm not sure what you're passing to that function.

Comment: @MrFlick Here it is: http://pastebin.com/RNJBRhGr

Comment: Yeah, your problem is with the `y` column. As per `?mlogit.data`, the `choice=` parameter should be logical, numeric, or a factor but your `y` value is character. Seems like you may have not imported your data correctly. You can replace `df1$y<-as.logical(df1$y)` and rerun your code and it should work.

Comment: @MrFlick Perfect, that works, thank you! So does `as.logical` basically declare y a boolean?